# How to properly get nvidia drivers/cuda setup for rtx a6000 workstation

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I am having issues setting up nvidia drivers/cuda on a rtx a6000 workstation, if it matters I am running 2 of them in nvlink.

I am on Fedora Workstation 39

I've tried multiple ways of installing the drivers from using rpmfusion, to directly getting the rpm from nvidia's site itself, both the standard rpm as well as the data center driver which seems to support the a6000.

No matter what I try, when I boot my pc after installing the drivers I get black lines going across the screen and fedora does it's usual boot sequence but then ends up on a black screen with a blinking terminal line.

I read that this may be due to incompatibility with the default graphics drivers in fedora so I ended up making a blacklist file with the following command:

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

none of this seemed to do anything different for me and always ended up with the same result, black lines going across screen, me having to uninstall drivers and try again.

Maybe I should try a different OS? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The driver version should be from the 535 branch (at the time of this writing). Is this the version you tried to install? And do you have Secure Boot enabled? Either disable it or manually sign the drivers otherwise they won't be loaded.